# Perl module Config::IniFiles error

Tags: perl, cpan

I am using Config::IniFiles module in my script to read the configuration file. I am getting the below error when executing the script.

```
List::Util version 1.33 required--this is only version 1.21 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Config/IniFiles.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Config/IniFiles.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at ./SFTP_Common_Connect.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./SFTP_Common_Connect.pl line 3.
```

The below is script lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Config::IniFiles;
use Data::Dumper;

my $conf="/tmp/config.cfg";
my %con_details;

(-f $conf) ? tie %con_details, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => $conf ) : die $!;

print Dumper %con_details;
```

Comment: It pretty much says there what's wrong --- your List::Util is too old. Upgrade that.

Comment: I have upgraded. Although, receiving the same error

Comment: @Madhan Then either the installation failed, or the module was installed somewhere that perl can't find it. Are you sure List::Util installed successfully? CPAN Testers shows [a number of failures on Perl 5.8.8](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Scalar-List-Utils%201.45;perl=5.8.8;reports=1). As an aside, you should *really* upgrade your perl version; 5.8.8 is over 10 years old!

Answer (score 3):

The message is pretty self explanatory.

> List::Util version 1.33 required--this is only version 1.21

One of the modules requires List::Util version 1.33, but you're loading an install of version 1.21. You need to install a newer version of List::Util.

You should use your OS distributions's package manager or `cpan` (or `cpanm`) to install modules, as they handle installing dependencies as well.

Comment: I have re-installed the updated List::Util and also installed the Config::IniFiles modules by cpan Config::IniFiles

Comment: The problem wasn't that List::Util wasn't installed, so let's assume you meant you installed List::Util 1.33, and let's assume you meant to say you are still having the problem. If that's true, there are numerous possibilities. Please specify how you installed the module. (Provide the exact command, please.) If you used `cpan`, provide the output of `echo 'o conf' | cpan`. Also, provide the output of `set | grep ^PERL`. (All of this you be added as an edit to your question.)

Comment: Now the List::Util module has updated in its recent version, which is 1.45. I have downloaded the Config::IniFiles from cpan and installed via the command cpan[4]> install Config::IniFiles.

Comment: 1) That's not even the right module. 2) Be more specific. How did you launch `cpan`? 3) What's the answer to the other questions. 4) Why are you posting that in a comment?

Comment: Two more pieces of info, please: The output of `which cpan` and of `head -n 1 \`which cpan\``

Comment: I have answered your questions in the above comment. Please assist where suppose to post my answers for your queries. I cant find the reply option. Then, the module has installed by another person. I have received the details as that he has downloaded the module from cpan tar.gz format and he installed using cpan install command.

Comment: Re "*I have answered your questions in the above comment*", No, you haven't provided ANY of the information I requested. // Re "*Please assist where suppose to post my answers for your queries*", Your Question is lacking in information. I pointed out which information is lacking. You need to fix your question, which can be done by using the "edit" link is provided. // Re "*Then, the module has installed by another person*", You told me you did it! ("I have re-installed the updated List::Util") So back to the beginning: What makes you think List::Util 1.33 is installed?

Comment: Yes. Another person done the Config::IniFiles installation. I done the re-installation for List::Util. It get updated with 1.45 version. :-) If possible pls suggest a way to resolve the issue:-) I mean what step I should take to work with that module?

Comment: I didn't mention Config::IniFiles a single time. Not sure why you keep bringing it up. /// Re "*If possible pls suggest a way to resolve the issue*", We require more information to do that. I've specified exactly what information we need to get started. The ball is in your court.

Comment: @Madhan how u resolved this issue ? I'm also stuck with the same

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your `Config::IniFiles` script requires newer `List::Util` version, than provided in your installation. Probably, you installed perl modules from different repositories.

You can find a location of `List::Util` by executing, ex, `perldoc -l List::Util`, then I recommend you to find which OS package installed old version, and update the package.

Other options are to install only fresh `List::Util` from CPAN, ex, `cpanp install List::Util`, or downgrade `Config::IniFiles`, installing old OS package.